# Echo only if it hasn't already been echoed?

Tags: php, arrays

What I'm trying to do is make a list of entries from a form, but I do not want the same entry to be displayed multiple times in the list if it was entered more than once in the form. For example, say one person enters "1" but then two people enter "2", I would only want the 2 to appear once in the list. What function would I be able to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use [PHP Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php). Arrays are 2-dimensional tables.

```php
/* Array
 * key => value
 * @key personID
 * @value optionValue
 */
$array = array(
    1 => 1, // Person 1 chose Option 1
    2 => 2, // Person 2 chose Option 2
    3 => 2  // Person 3 chose Option 2
);
print_r($array);
```

Prints

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 2 
    [3] => 2
)
```

You are now able to fetch a set of unique values by accessing the array via [`array_unique($array);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```php
$array_unique = array_unique($array);
$array_unique_values = array_values($array_unique);

// Access array values directly and store into variables.
// Notice that arrays in PHP start with the index zero.
$option1 = $array_unique_values[0];
$option2 = $array_unique_values[1];

echo "Option #1: " . $option1 . "\n";
echo "Option #2: " . $option2;
```

Prints

```
Option #1: 1
Option #2: 2
```

Voilà.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Please also consider [Languages > Types > Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [Array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) for further information about arrays and its functions in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The best way should be to store all your entries in an array (basic numerical indexed array) and then, remove duplicate with

```
uniqueEntries = array_unique($yourEntries);
```

The documentation : [array_unique](http://php.net/array_unique)

example of code:

```
$entries = array();
$entries[] = 1;
$entries[] = 1;
$entries[] = 2;

$entries = array_unique($entries);

print_r($entries);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, works like a charm! Thanks a lot!
Edit: in general, in the output, how would I be able to stop the "Array" text from appearing?

Comment: Don't understand your question. if you are talking about the array data, it is printed by `print_r()`.  Remove `print_r()` and you will not see the array anymore.

Comment: I think he ment how he could access the values directly, without the array construct around.

Answer (score 0):

You have no built-in function for that in PHP. But you could try with something like:

```
$echoList = array();
function echoOnce( $text )
{
   global $echoList;
   if(!in_array($text, $echoList)) {
      echo $text;
      $echoList[] = $text;
   }
}
```

And then just use `echoOnce( "whatever" )` instead of `echo "whatever"`

Comment: Using a global variable for something like this is unnecessary, not to mention that its introducing a global dependency into your code, and `in_array()` will perform an `O(n)` search just to output a variable. It seems very inefficient to me.